# Show alert message when I create or update data in SQL Server, .NET Core ADO.NET, Stored Procedure. And Create Stored Procedure in GetStudentData

Tags: .net-core, ado.net

When I Create, Update, or Delete the data from the View Page it shows a message or alert message.

I try to add an alert message in View Page, but it was not executed.

```
namespace StudentRecordManagementSystem.Models
```

{
public class StudentDataAccessLayer
{
string connectionString = ConnectionString.CName;

```
    public IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudent()  // Stored Procedure Method
    {
        List<Student> lstStudent = new List<Student>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllStudent", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Student student = new Student();
                student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                student.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                student.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                student.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                student.Mobile = rdr["Mobile"].ToString();
                student.Address = rdr["Address"].ToString();

                lstStudent.Add(student);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return lstStudent;
    }

    public Student GetStudentData(int? id)  // want to create like stored procedure
    {
        Student student = new Student();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Id= " + id;  // Not like this, Query statement

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                student.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                student.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                student.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                student.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                student.Mobile = rdr["Mobile"].ToString();
                student.Address = rdr["Address"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return student;
    }
}
```

}

> > > I created a method in Stored Procedure, however, it will not work.
> > > How I properly create the GetStudentData as Stored Procedure in ASP.NET Core ADO.NET.
> > > Don't want to create like string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Id= " + id;
> > > I create this example, they are using Stored Procedure in GetAllStudent() method and using
> > > Query in GetStudentData() method. For reference link: [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-using-asp-net-core-and-ado-net/][1]